# Pentaho - Formatting date in Mondrian

Tags: pentaho, mondrian, pentaho-spoon

I am getting date like **20150910** numeric from backend. 
I am creating new level in Dimension (in Mondrian-template)

Is there any way to format the date to 2015-09-10 ?

Can i achieve this using formatString ?

Any pointers will be highly appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a KeyExpression, which accepts SQL statements, then split the string in the various parts and concatenate it back with dashes in between.

See https://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php#XML_KeyExpression

Remark: if you use a KeyExpression you should not use a column attribute.